# find the branch name of a push in actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a branch called release/test I want to find the name of the branch before it gets push merged into main branch.

I was using  `if: ${{startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/release/')}}` to run a step but it just bypasses the if because github.ref is showing as refs/heads/main/ at that merge stage. At least thats what I think is happening.

Here is what I have and runs after I merge squash a pull request with my branch called release/test.
What I'm trying to do is capture that release branch name and only run my code if that branch has release in it.

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  Release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: "Bump package version"
        id: bumpVersion
        uses: "phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master"
        env:
         GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
         PACKAGEJSON_DIR: "./client"
         tag-prefix: ${{env.TAG_PREXIX}}
         major-wording: "MAJOR,BREAKING CHANGE:"
         minor-wording: "feat"
         patch-wording: "patch,fix,bugfix,chore"

      - name: "get branch name"
        if: ${{startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/release/')}}
        ...... act on my step if not pass
```